# SQL: send multiple request or one big request containing all the request?

Tags: sql, request

I was asking myself what was the optimal (in term of speed and security) solution between sending plenty SQL request (thousand) or concating it all in one and then send it to SQL?

The scenario is: we are on a nodejs server (multiple users), in a loop, at each iteration i can send a request to SQL or concat the request, and send one big request after the loop. The data is fixed.

Comment: It depends on the scenario. Please provide more info

Comment: what do you want me to precise ?

Comment: Context needed... Is this an application, a reporting suite. Will there be multiple users? Is the data fixed or likely to change during the query?

Comment: i edited the post, ask whatever you need more :)